# Ruby matrix addition to multi dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, ruby, matrix, narray

Multidimensional Matrix array is like this

```
arr1 = Matrix[[0.9742006046104146, 0.9164380106962612, 0.39571440216724874],  
              [1.3793903493310324, 1.8988033906016721, 1.2768961254764901], 
              [0.42334074004480604, 1.6728495387871951, 1.2575501206006443]]
```

Another simple array is like this

```
arr2 = Matrix[[0.13054527963360518, 0.8579042642337861, 0.3041160868559809]]
```

I can't add both together, `arr1 + arr2`

```
ExceptionForMatrix::ErrDimensionMismatch: Matrix dimension mismatch
    from /home/arjun/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/matrix.rb:996:in `+'
    from (irb):171
    from /home/arjun/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

How can I do it. In python/numpy simply doing an addition just works?
What is the Ruby equivalent?

*NOTE -*
*`arr1` is the dot product of `Matrix[*a] * Matrix[*b]`, if that matters*

Comment: What do you expect the output to look like?  Matrix addition is only defined when the two matrices have the same dimensions, as you can guess from the error.

Comment: In the python one, `arr2` is added to each row of `arr1`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you'd have to push the contents of the second matrix into the first matrix, maybe with either the spade operator `matrix_1 << matrix_2[0]`or the `.push` method.

p.s. I'd like to add, I've never used Matrix in ruby hence my 'guess' but since it's array like It's fair to assume that it has an array like API.